# finding keyword in excel coumn using For Loop

Tags: python

I have a column with data of sentences. and i have a list of keywords.

Using for for loop how can i iterate each rows to check with the row has the specific keyword from the list. and enter the keyword in another column

Note: without mentioning the keyword i wanna call it from list using index.

```
keyword: [sleeping, eating, walking]


df= {column:['vivek is sleeping','karti is eating','ramu is walking']}
```

i did it using Numpy.where and Numpy.select functions.

Could some one help me to do this for loop by calling the dataset instead of entering the string in syntax

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `any` to check the presence of an element from one list to another:

```
import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['vivek is sleeping','karti is eating','ramu is walking']})

keyword = ['sleeping', 'eating', 'walking']

## check if the keyword is present
df['is_available'] = df['column'].map(lambda x: any([y for y in x.split() if y in keyword]))

print(df)

    column            is_available
0   vivek is sleeping     True
1   karti is eating       True
2   ramu is walking       True
```